# Adding a new column in a table(grid) using displaytag

Tags: javascript, spring, displaytag

I have the following code for table using displaytag in my jsp page

```
   <display:table id="xyz" name="XYZ">
    <display:column title="Col1"  property="name"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Col2" format="{0,date,MM-dd-yyyy}" property="date1"/>
   </display:table>
```

Now i want to add another column dynamically(say date2) which should happen only if the resultset returned from database contains date2 column in it. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I think Display tag library doesn't provide any checking logic, in my view it is better to go with the jstl core **c:choose**. as like this

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <display:table id="xyz" name="XYZ">
        <display:column title="Col1"  property="name"></display:column>
        <display:column title="Col2" format="{0,date,MM-dd-yyyy}" property="date1"/>
           <c:choose>
                     <c:when test="${XYZ.date2!=null}">
                        <display:column title="Col3" format="{0,date,MM-dd-yyyy}" property="date2"/>
                     </c:when>
                   <c:otherwise>
                   </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>
    </display:table>
```

I hope this suites for your case, 
Have a great day bye